# UITableView property changing?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

can we change the color and other property of TableView , msg box, and other readymade ui ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Have a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)